# How to change max-width of reddit's embed comment iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, reddit

Reddit gives code to embed their comments on website,

for example:

```html
<div class="reddit-embed" data-embed-media="www.redditmedia.com" data-embed-parent="false" data-embed-live="false" data-embed-uuid="24a3e666-f855-4664-8e9e-9d040fef3ca6" data-embed-created="2016-06-29T16:56:02.732Z">
  <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/2safxv/we_should_start_keeping_giraffes_a_secret_from/cno7zic">Comment</a> from discussion <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/2safxv/we_should_start_keeping_giraffes_a_secret_from/">We should start keeping giraffes a secret from young children. Imagine discovering giraffes exist when you were like 15. &quot;Woah! Check out that long necked horse!&quot;</a>.
</div>
<script async src="https://www.redditstatic.com/comment-embed.js"></script>
```

When you paste it to HTML it renders `iframe` with content.

`max-width` property of this `iframe` is set to `800px`, how can I change it to other value or `none` ?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1skrto82/)

Comment: Why do you want to change it?  That's the maximum size it was designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to override the inline style which you don't have access, you need to use `!important` (this is the extremely cases you need to use `!important` , otherwise **avoid it**)

```css
iframe {
  max-width: none !important
}
```

```html
<div class="reddit-embed" data-embed-media="www.redditmedia.com" data-embed-parent="false" data-embed-live="false" data-embed-uuid="24a3e666-f855-4664-8e9e-9d040fef3ca6" data-embed-created="2016-06-29T16:56:02.732Z"><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/2safxv/we_should_start_keeping_giraffes_a_secret_from/cno7zic">Comment</a> from discussion <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/2safxv/we_should_start_keeping_giraffes_a_secret_from/">We should start keeping giraffes a secret from young children. Imagine discovering giraffes exist when you were like 15. &quot;Woah! Check out that long necked horse!&quot;</a>.</div>
<script
async src="https://www.redditstatic.com/comment-embed.js"></script>
```